# Why matrix multiply (float32_4x4) with armv8 NEON instructions is slower?

Tags: android, c++, arm, simd, neon

Below code is using NEON instructions (from UE4)

```
void matrixMultiplyNeon(float* ret, float32x4_t* A, float32x4_t* B) {

    float32x4_t * R = (float32x4_t*)ret;
    float32x4_t temp, r0, r1, r2, r3;

    auto low  = vget_low_f32(A[0]);
    auto high = vget_high_f32(A[0]);
    temp = vmulq_lane_f32(      B[0], low, 0);
    temp = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[1], low, 1);
    temp = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[2], high, 0);
    r0   = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[3], high, 1);

    low  = vget_low_f32(A[1]);
    high = vget_high_f32(A[1]);
    temp = vmulq_lane_f32(      B[0], low, 0);
    temp = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[1], low, 1);
    temp = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[2], high, 0);
    r1   = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[3], high, 1);

    low  = vget_low_f32(A[2]);
    high = vget_high_f32(A[2]);
    temp = vmulq_lane_f32(      B[0], low, 0);
    temp = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[1], low, 1);
    temp = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[2], high, 0);
    r2   = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[3], high, 1);

    low  = vget_low_f32(A[3]);
    high = vget_high_f32(A[3]);
    temp = vmulq_lane_f32(      B[0], low, 0);
    temp = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[1], low, 1);
    temp = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[2], high, 0);
    r3   = vmlaq_lane_f32(temp, B[3], high, 1);

    R[0] = r0;
    R[1] = r1;
    R[2] = r2;
    R[3] = r3;
}
```

Below code is my normal matrix multiply, use a array float[16]

```
void matrixMultiply(float* ret, float* m1, float* m2) {
    float product[16];
    product[0] = m1[0] * m2[0] + m1[4] * m2[1] + m1[8] * m2[2] + m1[12] * m2[3];
    product[1] = m1[1] * m2[0] + m1[5] * m2[1] + m1[9] * m2[2] + m1[13] * m2[3];
    product[2] = m1[2] * m2[0] + m1[6] * m2[1] + m1[10] * m2[2] + m1[14] * m2[3];
    product[3] = m1[3] * m2[0] + m1[7] * m2[1] + m1[11] * m2[2] + m1[15] * m2[3];
    product[4] = m1[0] * m2[4] + m1[4] * m2[5] + m1[8] * m2[6] + m1[12] * m2[7];
    product[5] = m1[1] * m2[4] + m1[5] * m2[5] + m1[9] * m2[6] + m1[13] * m2[7];
    product[6] = m1[2] * m2[4] + m1[6] * m2[5] + m1[10] * m2[6] + m1[14] * m2[7];
    product[7] = m1[3] * m2[4] + m1[7] * m2[5] + m1[11] * m2[6] + m1[15] * m2[7];
    product[8]  = m1[0] * m2[8] + m1[4] * m2[9] + m1[8] * m2[10] + m1[12] * m2[11];
    product[9]  = m1[1] * m2[8] + m1[5] * m2[9] + m1[9] * m2[10] + m1[13] * m2[11];
    product[10] = m1[2] * m2[8] + m1[6] * m2[9] + m1[10] * m2[10] + m1[14] * m2[11];
    product[11] = m1[3] * m2[8] + m1[7] * m2[9] + m1[11] * m2[10] + m1[15] * m2[11];
    product[12] = m1[0] * m2[12] + m1[4] * m2[13] + m1[8] * m2[14] + m1[12] * m2[15];
    product[13] = m1[1] * m2[12] + m1[5] * m2[13] + m1[9] * m2[14] + m1[13] * m2[15];
    product[14] = m1[2] * m2[12] + m1[6] * m2[13] + m1[10] * m2[14] + m1[14] * m2[15];
    product[15] = m1[3] * m2[12] + m1[7] * m2[13] + m1[11] * m2[14] + m1[15] * m2[15];
    memcpy(ret, product, sizeof(float) * 16);
}
```

The test is a 1024*1024 times for loop, result is :
NO NEON **366**ms
NEON    **428**ms

Why the NEON code is more slower and how to optimized ?

Comment: The compilers probably just producing more efficient assembly code than your hand coded version

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what compiler and compiler settings you use. But gcc uses NEON instructions automatically for the second implementation. See https://godbolt.org/z/eq81YeoEh

Comment: @Codo look carefully, in the second version they're all scalar operations (you can tell for example by the `s`-registers being used, instead of `q`-registers). Also there are far too many of them.

Comment: My test device's cpu is ARM Cortex-A53 , 2000 MHz, 8 cores

Comment: @harold: Oops. Yes, indeed.

Comment: Your code is a mess, even your C code. You should use local variables rather than directly accessing memories. And `memcpy` isn't free.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you use `vget_low` and/or `vget_high`, the compiler generates a mess.

Neon intrinsics is only usable for processing contiguous data where the input and output usually match 1:1. For permutations, you better write your code in assembly.

BTW, you should transpose the matrix A with `vld4`.

And consider using plain `float` pointers, NOT `float32x4_t *`

```
void matrixMultiplyNeon(float* ret, float* A, float* B) {

    float32x4x4_t matA, matB, rslt;

    matA = vld4q_f32(A);
    matB.val[0] = vld1q_f32(B);
    B += 4;
    matB.val[1] = vld1q_f32(B);
    B += 4;
    matB.val[2] = vld1q_f32(B);
    B += 4;
    matB.val[3] = vld1q_f32(B);

    rslt.val[0] = matA.val[0] * matB.val[0];
    rslt.val[0] += matA.val[1] * matB.val[0];
    rslt.val[0] += matA.val[2] * matB.val[0];
    rslt.val[0] += matA.val[3] * matB.val[0];

    rslt.val[1] = matA.val[0] * matB.val[1];
    rslt.val[1] += matA.val[1] * matB.val[1];
    rslt.val[1] += matA.val[2] * matB.val[1];
    rslt.val[1] += matA.val[3] * matB.val[1];

    rslt.val[2] = matA.val[0] * matB.val[2];
    rslt.val[2] += matA.val[1] * matB.val[2];
    rslt.val[2] += matA.val[2] * matB.val[2];
    rslt.val[2] += matA.val[3] * matB.val[2];

    rslt.val[3] = matA.val[0] * matB.val[3];
    rslt.val[3] += matA.val[1] * matB.val[3];
    rslt.val[3] += matA.val[2] * matB.val[3];
    rslt.val[3] += matA.val[3] * matB.val[3];

    vst4q_f32(ret, rslt);
}
```

Comment: Use your code ,  result is NO NEON 366ms vs NEON 220 ms :)

Comment: @JihuiXu That's quite disappointing. I expected below 100ms. Maybe you should check the disassembly.